# What is the correct way to implement an infinite loop using the Ruby PubNub asynchronous subscribe to channel example?

Tags: ruby, pubnub, fluentd

I have some Ruby code to subscribe to PubNub and relay what is read from a channel to Fluentd. I am periodically seeing some duplicate messages arrive in Fluentd. I suspect there is a problem using the infinite loop+sleep in the code below. What is the more correct way to achieve this? Many thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'pubnub'
require 'fluent-logger'

class Subscribe
  # spin loop delay
  DELAY = 0.5
  def initialize(subkey)
    @subkey = subkey
    # setup logger
    @log = Fluent::Logger::FluentLogger.new(nil, :host=>'localhost', :port=>24224)
  end
  def to_channel(channel)
    pubnub = Pubnub.new(
      subscribe_key: @subkey
    )
    pubnub.subscribe(channel: channel) do |envelope|
      #puts envelope.message
      @log.post("some-tag", envelope.message)
    end
    # never end
    loop do
      sleep(DELAY)
    end
  end
end

args = Hash[ ARGV.join(' ').scan(/--?([^=\s]+)(?:=(\S+))?/) ]
channel = args['channel']

if channel and channel != ""
  sub  = Subscribe.new('sub-key-here')
  sub.to_channel(channel)
else
  puts "usage: #{$PROGRAM_NAME} --channel=<channel name>"
end
```

Comment: It looks like your loop does nothing but sleep. Is that all your loop should be doing?

Comment: Yes, but I am wondering whether that plays nicely with EventMachine used by the PubNub code.